# Update view using MVI with Mosby

Tags: android, mosby

I am using the [Mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) library and MVI as described here: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1

My question is about how to wire up a Presenter to render a model, if the model is received from the "business logic" layer, but not directly in response to an Intent from its View.

For example, PresenterA receives an intent from ViewA, forwards it to the  business logic which then needs to send an updated state to both PresenterA and PresenterB (for rendering in ViewA and ViewB).

However, since the intent originated in ViewA (not ViewB) how should PresenterB be configured (in `bindIntents()`) to render that new state?

I tried having the business layer expose a `BehaviorSubject` that the presenter would observe:

```
override fun bindIntents() {
    var updatesFromIntent = 
            intent(MyView::intent).flatMap { businessLogic.fromIntent() }
    val viewStateUpdates : Observable<ViewState> = 
            Observable.merge(updatesFromIntent, businessLogic.behaviorSubject)
    subscribeViewState(viewStateUpdates, MyView::render)
}
```

But the number of subscribers to the subject grows whenever `onNext` is called, which concerns me.

Comment: what is `businessLogic.fromIntent()` doing?

Comment: It was creating a new view state, pushing it to the `behaviorSubject` and returning the `behaviorSubject`.  This was a bad idea, and now I return the view state observable directly.  Since my presenter needs to listen to that subject for other updates (not just in response to intents on it's view) I was trying to just communicate with the presenter through the subject. Is subscribing to a subject for updates that are unrelated to intents created by the view a valid use case?  It's not something I noticed in your (very helpful) samples.